# Open nyroModal window inside qTip

Tags: jquery, qtip, nyromodal, qtip2

I'm using **qTip2** and one of my tooltip is in tag DIV. Inside that DIV I have a link which should open a **nyroModal** window (ajax page). It's opening only 1st time and the next one when i hover and clik on link opening as simple page like `target="_blank"`.

Here is a Live Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/Ja9dN/2/**

**HTML:**

```
<div style="margin:50px 0 0 50px">

    <span class="qTip">Hover to see the Tooltip with Content</span>

    <div class="qTipContent">...<a href="http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/" class="modalBox">This link</a> opens nyroModal window only once ...  </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/" class="modalBox">This link open window</a></p>


</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.qTip').qtip({
               content: {
                  text: function(api) {
                      return $('.qTipContent');
                  }
               },
               position: {
                  my: 'bottom center',
                  at: 'top center',
                  adjust: {y: 0 }
               },
               style: {
                  classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded',
                  width: 390
                  },            
               hide: {
                  delay: 250,
                  fixed: true
               }               
});

$(".modalBox").nyroModal();
```

Thanks

**SOLVED:**

changed the content call to:

```
content: {
    text: $('.qTipContent')                  
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how qTip2 works, or if there are compatibility issues or... but I think that a possible explanation is the loss of the link between the link - tag a - and the click handler because of a refresh of the div for example... So you could try inserting the code directly after the link:

```
<p>
<a href="http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/" class="modalBox">This link open window</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(function() {
        $(".modalBox").nyroModal();
    });
});
</script>
</p>
```

Comment: changed: 
content: {
text: $('.qTipContent')                  
}  and it helped :)